# Optimize an underdetermined system with quartic constraints

Tags: optimization, mathematical-programming

I encountered an optimization problem which does not belong to any well-known category of optimization.

The system has $M$ (typically $M=120$) real variables and $N$ (typically $N=100$) constraints (all of them are equations), where $M>N$. Thus, all constraints can be satisfied.

The objective function is linear (weighted sum).

Some constraints are quartic **equations** (all terms are degree 4). Other constraints are quadratic **equations** (all terms are degree 2).

How to solve such optimization problem? I imagine there are two (possible) general approaches:

- mathematical programming approach, e.g. nonlinear programming.
  However, I find no specific program which fits the configurations
  above.
- meta-heuristics, e.g., hill-climbing or simulated annealing. I do not
  prefer this approach because it does not address the nature of
  under-determined system.

Comment: Oh, I see you also posted this on SciComp.SE: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3117184/14578.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it was also posted on SciComp.SE.

Comment: The question on SciComp has now been removed so I think we should reopen this.

Comment: The copy on SciComp is gone, but the question on Math.SE is still there, and I answered this question on Math.SE: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3117184/14578.  Did that answer meet your needs?  If not, please edit the question to clarify your requirements and identify which requirement(s) that answer doesn't meet.

Comment: Yes, the answer meet my needs. I also posted my research.